# Unable to fetch the record from CKContainer.default().userRecordID() after deploying CloudKit from Development to Production

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit, ckreference

I have just built my first app that uses CloudKit and is working fine in the development environment. I have now deployed my container to Production but while testing in this production environment, the app does not work.

The user creates a profile on the app. This is a CKRecord created from Container.default().userRecordID() and is then subsequently stored on a public container in CloudKit. This works perfectly in the development environment.

For beta testing using TestFlight, I deployed my container to Production. The userRecordID in both development and production is the same. However, the CKRecord I fetch using this userRecordID returns a nil value and the reason my app is not working. I'm able to fetch  a CKRecord in the development environment.

Would be very grateful if anyone can help me with I'm missing.

I have tested this app using a simulator. If the record itself is returning a nil value, I doubt my app will work on the device. I have created the com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment in the Entitlements file and set it to Production.

Below is the code snippet
Xcode  - 14.0.1
iOS - 16.0

```
import CloudKit

final class CloudKitManager {
    
    static let shared = CloudKitManager()

    private init(){}
    
    var userRecord: CKRecord?
    var profileRecordID: CKRecord.ID?
    var clinicRecordID: CKRecord.ID?
    let container = CKContainer.default()
    var getUserRecordHasFired : Bool = false
    var accountStatus: CKAccountStatus = .couldNotDetermine
    
    
    func checkAccountStatus() async throws -> CKAccountStatus {try await container.accountStatus()}
    
    func getAccountStatus() async {
        do{
            accountStatus = try await checkAccountStatus()
            print(accountStatus)
        } catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func getUserRecord() async throws {
        
        let recordID = try await container.userRecordID()
        print(recordID) //This returns a recordID in both development and production.
    
        let record = try await container.publicCloudDatabase.record(for: recordID)
        userRecord = record
        print(record["userProfile"]) //This returns a CKRecord in development but nil in       production.
    

        if let profileReference = record["userProfile"] as? CKRecord.Reference {
            profileRecordID = profileReference.recordID
            print("profile record ID \(profileRecordID)")
            guard let profileRecordID = profileRecordID else {return}
            
            let profileRecord = try await container.publicCloudDatabase.record(for: profileRecordID)
            
            let profile = DCProfile(record: profileRecord)
            
            clinicRecordID = profile.hasClinic.recordID
            
        }
        
        getUserRecordHasFired = true
    }
}
```